How can I plot a column that's full of nan values?
I have code that runs through a GeoJSON file and plots columns from that file one by one to show the user the costs of an optimisation. It ran fine, until it came across a column of just nan values.
I did some looking into this and discovered that the GeoPandas (v0.14.4) plotting file firstly creates a list of which values are nan:
nan_idx = np.asarray(pd.isna(values), dtype="bool")

then it resets the values variable to contain all the values that are not nan:
values = cat.codes[~nan_idx]

and then it fills nans with a placeholder so that it can properly plot them:
for n in np.where(nan_idx)[0]:
    values = np.insert(values, n, values[0])

and this is where the issue is! As the column just contains nans, I get an IndexError from values[0] as it's now empty. This was reconfirmed by changing one value to a float and it working perfectly; plotting the nans as missing values.
Can anyone tell me if there is another way to plot columns containing all nan values or if this issue has been developed upon in newer versions of GeoPandas? It's important to show that the values are all "missing values", as that will just show that that specific column is not feasible.
All the above code is found in the geopandas/plotting.py file for GeoPandas (v0.14.4) and happens within the plot() function in the snippet of my code below (where name is the column name and hexagons refer to a Geopandas df):
import geopandas as gpd
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_and_save(crs, name, legend_kwds, output_folder, figsize=(10,5), legend=True, cmap='viridis_r', 
             missing_kwds={"color": "lightgrey", "label": "Missing values",},
             bbox_inches="tight",
             ):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=figsize)
    ax = plt.axes(projection=crs)
    ax.set_axis_off()

    hexagons.to_crs(crs.proj4_init).plot(
        ax=ax,
        column = name,
        legend = legend,
        cmap = cmap,
        legend_kwds = legend_kwds,
        missing_kwds = missing_kwds,
    )

    ax.set_title(name)
    fig.savefig(output_folder + f"/{name}.png", bbox_inches=bbox_inches)
    plt.close()

hexagons = gpd.read_file("results/hexfile.geojson")

hexagon_bounds = hexagons.geometry.bounds    
min_lon, min_lat = hexagon_bounds[['minx','miny']].min()
max_lon, max_lat = hexagon_bounds[['maxx','maxy']].max()

central_lon = (min_lon + max_lon)/2
central_lat = (min_lat + max_lat)/2

crs = ccrs.Orthographic(central_longitude = central_lon, central_latitude= central_lat)

output_folder = 'plots/results'

plot_and_save(crs, 'pipeline transport costs', {'label':'pipeline cost [euros/kg]'}, output_folder) 

Here is how a plot looks when it has values for everything:

And here is a plot which only has one value, I would like to have a plot that is just fully greyed out:


To handle columns that consist only of NaN values, you can add a check before the plotting step to ensure the column isn't empty or filled with NaN values. If it is, you can either skip the plot for that column or provide a placeholder value. Here's an updated version of your code that should help:
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

def plot_with_nan_check(hexagons, name, figsize=(10, 10), crs=None, legend=False, cmap='viridis', 
                        legend_kwds=None, missing_kwds=None, output_folder='./', bbox_inches='tight'):
    
    # Check if the column contains only NaN values
    if hexagons[name].isna().all():
        print(f"Column '{name}' contains only NaN values.")
        # Handle this case, e.g., by assigning a placeholder value or skipping the plot
        values = np.zeros(len(hexagons))  # You can adjust this placeholder value as needed
    else:
        values = hexagons[name]

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=figsize)
    ax = plt.axes(projection=crs)
    ax.set_axis_off()

    hexagons.to_crs(crs.proj4_init).plot(
        ax=ax,
        column=name,
        legend=legend,
        cmap=cmap,
        legend_kwds=legend_kwds,
        missing_kwds=missing_kwds,
    )

    ax.set_title(name)
    fig.savefig(output_folder + f"/{name}.png", bbox_inches=bbox_inches)
    plt.close()


Please format your code...

Sorry, but rep is not obtained through begging. Also it's not SO community's role to do your school's job of assessing your progres, teachers are paid for that.

Hi Laurentiu, thank you for your response. I have edited my question as I realise that it could have been clearer in the fact that, aside from the snippet at the end, all the code mentioned happens in the plot() function in the geopandas/plotting.py file for GeoPandas (v0.14.4) and therefore I cannot reset the "values" variable to something of my liking. I know that I can change the column values to a placeholder, but I would like GeoPandas to plot that whole column as missing values if it only contains NaNs. I do not want to skip that column. Again, thank you for your response.
